# Модуль, указанный в импорте кода python, не находит на heroku (не добавляет в git?)

Tags: git, github, python-import

[image: Про GitHub ничего не знаю, установил его только сейчас: в нем в графе Pipfile отсутствует speechrecognition, в этом дело?]Всем здравствуйте.

Отнеситесь, пожалуйста, с пониманием, знаний по теме совсем мало или никаких, но попытаюсь описать, что у меня не получается: добавляю своего Telegram-бота в git, один из указанных в python-коде модулей (speechrecognition), кажется, не экспортируется (не вижу его в GitHub). Сначала Heroku жаловался на ModuleNotFoundError, поэтому я решил проверить, если в git добавляется. Модуль устанавливал через терминал PyCharm, находясь в папке-директиве моего проекта (командой pip install SpeechRecognition).

В requirements.txt, который в папке проекта PyCharm лежит указано следующее: APScheduler==3.6.3 beautifulsoup4==4.8.2 cachetools==4.2.2 certifi==2021.10.8 charset-normalizer==2.0.12 distlib==0.3.4 filelock==3.6.0 google==2.0.3 idna==3.3 pep8==1.7.1 pipenv==2022.5.2 platformdirs==2.5.2 pyTelegramBotAPI==4.5.1 python-telegram-bot==13.11 pytz==2022.1 pytz-deprecation-shim==0.1.0.post0 requests==2.27.1 six==1.16.0 soupsieve==1.9.5 **SpeechRecognition==3.8.1** tornado==6.1 tzdata==2022.1 tzlocal==4.2 urllib3==1.26.9 virtualenv==20.14.1 virtualenv-clone==0.5.7

Когда запускаю бота в PyCharm, в телеге он работает нормально, только на хероку не смог запустить.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне решить эту задачу? Как добавлять все необходимые для исполнения моего кода модули в git (импортированные модули)?

Спасибо!

Comment: Не нужно установленные зависимости добавлять в git, это непереносимо и работать не будет, даже если добавите. Создайте файл в корне проекта `requirements.txt`, в нем добавьте все зависимости (все то, что вы устанавливаете через `pip install xxx`), по одному пакету в строке, и heroku установит их все автоматически. Нужно только добавить `requirements.txt` в git.

Comment: Роман, я так и сделал, но Хероку пожаловался.

Comment: Добавил к моему вопросу скриншот Гитхаба, посмотрите сверху : там, в файле под заголовком Pipfile отсутствует speechrecognition, может в этом дело?

Comment: В вопросе это никак не отражено, там вы пишете другое - нужно исправить, чтоб было написано то, что вы делали. Одно дело локально выполнять команду `pip install ...`, а совсем другое добавить зависимости в `requirements.txt`. Добавьте в вопрос содержимое файла `requirements.txt`. Вы его действительно создали и поместили в git?

Comment: Еще объясните, что означает "не вижу его в GitHub". Как вы смотрите? Где ожидаете его увидеть?

Comment: Я никогда не работал с GitHub, скачал его сегодня в первый раз, но там отобразились все мои действия с git, которые я в терминале PyCharm провел. Смотрите скриншот, который я добавил к вопросу выше.